# How to decode this line of code?

Tags: java, decode, urlencode

```
&#47;Detail&#63;entitytype&#61;2&#38;searchtype&#61;2&#38;id&#61;1749495&#38;start&#61;101&#38;end&#61;200
```

Is it UTF-8 or Unicode? I've tried both, but neither one of them works. Is there any function in Java that can decode it?

Comment: Agree -- this has nothing to do with Java that I can see.

Comment: used in web addresses. at least i *think* so :P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HttpUtility in apache class, called org.apache.common that is package handle all the entities

Answer (score 7):

Those are HTML entities.
It decodes to

`/Detail?entitytype=2&searchtype=2&id=1749495&start=101&end=200`

Comment: apache commons has a utility. see http://commons.apache.org/lang/api-2.6/org/apache/commons/lang/StringEscapeUtils.html and take a look at unescapeHtml()

Comment: To decode that using java, try adding the text to a `JEditorPane`

Comment: You don't need a full blown library for this. Unless of course, you can use ProGuard.

Comment: @LanguagesNamedAfterCofee - I agree, though many non-trival projects will already be using commons-lang. Of course, the source code is freely available, and one could learn/crib from that if one wanted to re-write unescapeHtml()...

Answer (score 0):

It has nothing to do with charset or encoding, they are just [character entity references](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_XML_and_HTML_character_entity_references).